# how to request payment using google pay to merchant iD

Tags: java, android, google-pay

i what to send some employees with my app and collect some money from client to my account so i am planning to created a employees app where they can put client UIP id and amount and collect the amount to my account  how can i do this in my research i understand that i need a merchant iD so i created one on the google Wallet Console  and i dont know what to do next

my doubts

1, is this possible using google pay

2, i dont want  my google pay account on employees mobile

3, how to make use of the merchant id and request money using employees google pay to my merchant ID

so far i am able to send money from my own gpay to others

[GooglePay tutorial](https://developers.google.com/pay/api/android/guides/tutorial#checkoutactivity.java-java)
i found this code but i dont know how to use this

```
    private static JSONObject getGatewayTokenizationSpecification() throws JSONException {
    return new JSONObject() {{
      put("type", "PAYMENT_GATEWAY");
      put("parameters", new JSONObject() {{
        put("gateway", "example");
        put("gatewayMerchantId", "exampleGatewayMerchantId");
      }});
    }};
    }
```

i want to do this on secure way need help a set by step guide much appreciated

Comment: Why not let your employees carry the QR to your merchant account? The customer can scan the QR and feed the amount while making the payment. You can also register with one of the Payment Service Providers listed at https://developers.google.com/pay/api (under section Participating processors) and have them handle the transaction instead.

Comment: i want to control the amount and also check the amount requested came through then activate some control for client . this a 3 app situation employees app client app and an admin app all connected to a fire base database